# Notation for diagonal of Hessian

Tags: notation

Possible brain fart here, but is there a common, compact notation for the diagonal of the Hessian, i.e. the vector of second partial derivatives $(\partial_{x_1,x_1}^2f,\partial_{x_2,x_2}^2f,..., \partial_{x_n,x_n}^2f)$? Does $\partial_\mathbf{x}^2f$ do it, or would that generally be interpreted as meaning the Hessian matrix as a whole? Ideally something more compact than $\textrm{diag} (H(f))$ or $\textrm{diag} (D^2(f))$. If $\partial_\mathbf{x}^2f$ is not in common usage, I guess I can just use that and define it.

Comment: I don't know that notation, but if you define it, you can use it.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Sure, but if it's in common usage meaning something similar but different, it would be confusing for people used to the other meaning. I'll just use it anyway though.

Comment: You could write something like $\mathcal{H}_d(f)$ with components $\mathcal{H}_d(f)_i=\partial_{ii}^2 f$. But I like the one you came up with too as long as you define it (otherwise I'd think it referred to the full Hessian).